# QGIS: moving layers inside Layertree into a group crashes QGIS using python

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to reorder the result of a model using python in the layer tree. For this purpose I wrote a script that takes the name and group as well as the the desired layer position in this group as input.
Unfortunately this script is highly instable and is crashing my QGIS on a regular basis:

```
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    """
    Here is where the processing itself takes place.
    """

    # Retrieve the feature source and sink. The 'dest_id' variable is used
    # to uniquely identify the feature sink, and must be included in the
    # dictionary returned by the processAlgorithm function.
    targetName = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.INPUT,
        context
    )
    targetIndex = self.parameterAsInt(
        parameters,
        self.INPUTINDEX,
        context
    )
    targetGroup = self.parameterAsString(
        parameters,
        self.INPUTGRUPPE,
        context
    )

    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    layers = root.children()

    for item in layers:
        if item.name()==targetName:
            clonedlayer = item.clone()
            g = root.findGroup(targetGroup)
            g.insertChildNodes(targetIndex, [clonedlayer])
            root.removeChildNode(item)
        
    dest_id="success"
    return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

Does anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong here?
QGIS Version 3.28
MacBook Pro M2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are modifying the layer tree in the `processAlgorithm()` method of a processing script, which is not thread safe. This is why QGIS is crashing.

[This section of the docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#flags) gives the following tip:

> By default, Processing runs algorithms in a separate thread in order
> to keep QGIS responsive while the processing task runs. If your
> algorithm is regularly crashing, you are probably using API calls
> which are not safe to do in a background thread. Try returning the
> QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading flag from your algorithm’s
> flags() method to force Processing to run your algorithm in the main
> thread instead.

Therefore, if you are going to implement this logic in the `processAlgorithm()` method of a processing script, you will need to override the `flags()` method and return the `NoThreading` flag:

```py
def flags(self):
    return QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading
```

So an example script would be:

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QVariant
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                        QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                        QgsProcessingParameterString,
                        QgsProcessingParameterNumber)
                       
class ExAlgo(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    INPUTINDEX = 'INPUTINDEX'
    INPUTGRUPPE = 'INPUTGRUPPE'
 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
    def name(self):
        return "addlayertogroup"
         
    def displayName(self):
        return "Add layer to group"
 
    def group(self):
        return "Examples"
 
    def groupId(self):
        return "examples"
 
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return "Adds a layer to a layer tree group"
 
    def helpUrl(self):
        return "https://qgis.org"
         
    def createInstance(self):
        return type(self)()
   
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(self.INPUT, "Input layer"))
        
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber(self.INPUTINDEX, "Group insertion index"))
        
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString(self.INPUTGRUPPE, "Group name"))
        
    def flags(self):
        return QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading
    
    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        
        targetName = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )
        targetIndex = self.parameterAsInt(
            parameters,
            self.INPUTINDEX,
            context
        )
        targetGroup = self.parameterAsString(
            parameters,
            self.INPUTGRUPPE,
            context
        )

        root = context.project().layerTreeRoot()
        layers = root.children()

        for item in layers:
            if item.name()==targetName:
                clonedlayer = item.clone()
                g = root.findGroup(targetGroup)
                g.insertChildNodes(targetIndex, [clonedlayer])
                root.removeChildNode(item)
        
        return {}
```

Another option is to export your model as a Python Script Algorithm and edit it to include a `QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface` class which you can set to your output layer. The post-processor is called from the main thread, so it is safe to interact with gui elements such as canvas, layer tree etc. You can also check if the output layer will be loaded on completion and only set the post processor if affirmative.

Here is an example which you can adapt:

```py
"""
Model exported as python.
Name : Test
Group : 
With QGIS : 33003
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProcessing
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingAlgorithm
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterExtent
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterString
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterNumber
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface

import processing


class Test(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterExtent('input_extent', 'Input extent', defaultValue=None))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterString('output_group', 'Output group', multiLine=False, defaultValue=''))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('position_index', 'position index', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, defaultValue=0))
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('Output_layer', 'Output_layer', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, defaultValue=None))

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
        # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
        # overall progress through the model
        feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(1, model_feedback)
        results = {}
        outputs = {}

        # Create grid
        alg_params = {
            'CRS': 'ProjectCrs',
            'EXTENT': parameters['input_extent'],
            'HOVERLAY': 0,
            'HSPACING': 100,
            'TYPE': 0,  # Point
            'VOVERLAY': 0,
            'VSPACING': 100,
            'OUTPUT': parameters['Output_layer']
        }
        outputs['CreateGrid'] = processing.run('native:creategrid', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        results['Output_layer'] = outputs['CreateGrid']['OUTPUT']
        
        # Check if the output layer is going to be loaded after running the algorithm and..
        # if so, we instanciate the post processor class, passing the input parameters
        # group name & index (of course you could hard code these values for simplicity)
        # then we set the post processor to the output layer details
        if context.willLoadLayerOnCompletion(results['Output_layer']):
            context.layerToLoadOnCompletionDetails(results['Output_layer']).setPostProcessor(GroupOutputLayer.create(parameters['output_group'],
                                                                                                                    parameters['position_index']))
        return results

    def name(self):
        return 'Test'

    def displayName(self):
        return 'Test'

    def group(self):
        return ''

    def groupId(self):
        return ''

    def createInstance(self):
        return Test()

# Define a Post Processor class to add the output layer to a layer tree group
# This will be called from the main thread so QGIS won't crash :-)
class GroupOutputLayer(QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface):
    
    instance = None
    group_name = None
    position = None

    def postProcessLayer(self, layer, context, feedback):
        if not self.group_name or not self.position:
            return
        project = context.project()
        root_group = project.layerTreeRoot()
        if not root_group.findGroup(self.group_name):
            root_group.insertGroup(0, self.group_name)
        group1 = root_group.findGroup(self.group_name)
        lyr_node = root_group.findLayer(layer.id())
        if lyr_node:
            node_clone = lyr_node.clone()
            group1.insertChildNode(self.position, node_clone)
            lyr_node.parent().removeChildNode(lyr_node)
    
    # Hack to work around sip bug!
    @staticmethod
    def create(group_name, position) -> 'GroupOutputLayer':
        """
        Returns a new instance of the post processor, keeping a reference to the sip
        wrapper so that sip doesn't get confused with the Python subclass and call
        the base wrapper implementation instead...
        """
        GroupOutputLayer.group_name = group_name
        GroupOutputLayer.position = position
        GroupOutputLayer.instance = GroupOutputLayer()
        return GroupOutputLayer.instance
```

Acknowledgement to Nyall Dawson for the original example of the post processor class adapted here.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Riccardo, great! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can share with you my code that changes the order of layers in a group (parent). Previously, the nodes (layers) are ordered by the name of the layer using a function that I do not publish here. **My method does not use cloning**, maybe this will help you.

```
# ADD SORTED LAYERS (NODES) TO THE LAYERS TREE
for idx, node in enumerate(sorted_nodes):
    parent = node.parent()
    parent.insertLayer(idx + 1, node.layer())   
    parent.removeChildNode(node)
```

Comment: sorted_nodes is the result of root.children() result in your case?

Comment: Everytime I try to remove a Layer QGIS crashes.

Comment: In my case `layerTreeView().selectedNodes()`, then the node type is checked `if isinstance(node, QgsLayerTreeLayer)`, if the node is a layer, then the node is added to the list, which is then ordered by `node.layer().name()` and is passed to this loop.